# How to get Oracle Package specification metadata?

Tags: oracle, metadata

Is it possible to get information about all types, variables, constants, exceptions, cursors, and subprograms declared in cursor specification from metadata tables without parsing DDL?

Answer (score 0):

Information about procedures and the associated arguments can be found by querying the user_procedures and user_arguments views.

My PLSQL Developer tool also shows additional information about packages such as all public variables and cursors. But I don't know how that is done.